# Longjmp arguments give a type error

Tags: c, setjmp

I am trying to call longjmp. Setjmp works, but longjmp gives me a type error.

```
void thread_start_threading(void)
{
    setjmp(env);
    dispatch();
    current_thread->function(current_thread->arg);
}
```

And then later:

```
void thread_yield(void)
{
    longjmp(env, 9); 
    return;
}
```

The error it gives me is `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘longjmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`

What I really want is to save the state of the registers and then restore them later. I don't think i need to use the argument to do that. But I could be wrong. I don't grok setjmp.

EDIT: More code

Comment: Is the `env` used in the `longjmp` the same as the `env` used in the `setjmp`?  Could there be a different `env` in scope?  Where is the `while` that goes with the `do`?

Comment: There is only one env, and I just forgot to paste the while part.

Comment: Run the source file through the C preprocessor (gcc -E) and see what the compiler is really compiling.

Comment: Why are you passing `9` to `longjmp` when you are ignoring the return value of `setjmp`?

Comment: I don't actually need that value for anything (at this iteration), but `longjmp` requires a second argument.

Comment: @brandon: show  more code

Comment: For whatever reason, the compiler thinks that `env` has an integer type instead of an array type (`jmp_buf` is required to be an array type of some sort by the C language standard).  So double-check the declaration of `env` and make sure it's not being `#define`d by a macro somewhere.